# 2 DIVs in 1 parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 2 divs to stay side-by-side in one parent div, but with no succes. First time it worked partially good, with that I mean I had the image positioned in the DIV from the right, but after redimensioning things got messed up and I can't figure it out. I am beginner, so please make it simple.

```css
div.surf2
{
 position:absolute;
 background: #41c3ac;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surfleft
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 45%;
 padding-top: 80px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surf2right
{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 600px;
 width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf2">
    <div class="surfleft">
     <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
         <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
         <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
            <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english combining fun with hard-working.</li>   
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="surf2right">
    <img src="console.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding-left` as this instantly makes the div go over 100%. Add `float: left` to both div's and that should do it (you can also remove `display: inline-block`).

```css
div.surf2
{
 position:absolute;
 background: #41c3ac;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surfleft
{
 width: 45%;
 padding-top: 80px;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surf2right
{
 height: 600px;
 width: 55%;
}

div.surf2right, div.surfleft {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf2">
    <div class="surfleft">
     <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
         <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
         <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
            <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english combining fun with hard-working.</li>   
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="surf2right">
    <img src="console.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, it works perfectly now but I don't understand why. Setting float: left shouldn't make them overlap? Why did you say can also? Why is it optional?

Comment: Check this: [https://jsfiddle.net/89vzbeaq/](https://jsfiddle.net/89vzbeaq/). Inline-block elements have a bit of default spacing between them (as a normal inline element would have), this can sometimes cause undesirable effects, such as div's breaking to the next line. Check this article out for more information: [https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: **To the downvoter** - please explain the reason for downvoting my answer?

Comment: Oh, I see. The thing with the inline-block makes perfectly sense knowing I have 2 DIVs without any extra space left. But for the float. Why adding separately float: left doesn't work? And why using float: left, float: right doesn't work?

Comment: And also, how to add some space to the elements within the left div, without using padding?

Answer (score 1):

The `inline-block` always has a space. Either you use `float: left;` or remove the space:

```css
div.surf2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #41c3ac;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surfleft {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf2right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 600px;
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf2">
  <div class="surfleft">
    <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
    <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
      <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
      <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english combining fun with hard-working.</li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="surf2right">
    <img src="console.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And yeah, remove the `padding-left` or use `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
div.surf2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #41c3ac;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surfleft {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  height: 600px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.surf2right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 600px;
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf2">
  <div class="surfleft">
    <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
    <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
      <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
      <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english combining fun with hard-working.</li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="surf2right">
    <img src="console.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#content {

width: 980px;
height: 500px;
padding: 20 20 20 20;
background-color: #00fcff }
#package_update {

width: 680;
height: 500;
float: left;
background-color: #aaaaaa }
#previous_update {

width: 280;
height: 500;
float: right;
background-color: #ffcc00 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

<div id="package_update"></div>
<div id="previous_update"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.surf2 {
    width: fit-content;
    position:absolute;
    background: #41c3ac;
    height: 600px;
}


.surf2 div.surfleft {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 600px;
 }

.surf2 div.surfright {
    float:right;
 }

 <div class="surf2">
    <div class="surfleft">
        <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
         <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
            <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
            <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english combining fun with hard-working.</li>   
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="surf2right">
    <img src="console.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

width: fit-content will make the div the width of both divs inside it